# Concatenate strings and expression results in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, string-concatenation

I want to write out the current process ID in PowerShell. This works:

```
$processId = $([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess()).Id
Write-Output "My process ID is $processId"
```

However, I want to do it in one line, if possible. Substituting the `$([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess()).Id` for the variable doesn't seem to evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
'My process id is {0}' -f [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Id
```

And if we use automatic variables:

```
'My process id is {0}' -f $pid
```

Comment: Oh, I like that - easy string formatting. I'm changing my accepted answer to this one.

Answer (score 9):

This might be a tad simpler:

```
$pid
```

or

```
"My process id is $pid"
```

For more info about automatic variables execute:

```
man about_automatic_variables
```

Comment: +1 Although my question was mainly about string concatenation this is very helpful to know, too.

Comment: Yeah for that you want to use the `subexpression operator` inside the string e.g. "blah $(..expression..) yada".  PowerShell will evaluate the expression inside the `$()` (ie subexpression) and render the results to a string and insert that string at that location.

Answer (score 8):

```
Write-Output "My process ID is $([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Id)"
```

Basically you just needed to move the closing parenthesis after the Id.